# Use for loop count being ignored when using cin in C++

Tags: c++, input, cin

I have a for loop set up to take in user input X amount of times based on the number of nodes used for an adjacency list for this depth first search algorithm.

```
int nodeNum;

cout << "Number of nodes?: " << endl;
cin >> nodeNum;

cout << "Names: " << endl;
for (int i = 0; i < nodeNum; i++)
{
    getline(cin, tempName);

    v.push_back(tempName); //pushing the name of node into a vector
}
```

When I submit this into the online compiler of my university and GCC, it skips the last input. Example - I put in the number 8, it'll only take 7 nodes. How can I fix this?

Comment: How do you check the number of nodes after loop?

Comment: the number of nodes is determined when the user enters the nodeNum integer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The statement `cin >> nodeNum` reads the integer but leaves the file pointer immediately *after* the integer, but *before* the newline.

So the first iteration of the loop reads that newline as the first line. You can see this effect with:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(void) {
    int nodeNum;
    string tempName;

    cout << "Number of nodes?\n";
    cin >> nodeNum;

    cout << "Names:\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < nodeNum; i++)
    {
        getline(cin, tempName);
        cout << "[" << tempName << "]\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

with the sample run:

```
Number of nodes?
2xx
Names:
[xx]
aaa
[aaa]
```

*One* way to fix that is to place:

```
cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

immediately after the `cin >> nodeNum` - this clears out the characters until the end of the current line. You need to include the `<limits>` header file to use that.

Applying that change to the example code above:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
using namespace std;

int main(void) {
    int nodeNum;
    string tempName;

    cout << "Number of nodes?\n";
    cin >> nodeNum;
    cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');

    cout << "Names:\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < nodeNum; i++)
    {
        getline(cin, tempName);
        cout << "[" << tempName << "]\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

improves the situation markedly:

```
Number of nodes?
2xx
Names:
aaa
[aaa]
bbb
[bbb]
```

Comment: Note that if you *just* want to skip the end of the line if it's empty, you can use `std::ws`: http://ideone.com/vdzU2q